# Is there a way to stepinto opencl kernel code running on mac

Tags: debugging, opencl

Is there a way to step into OpenCL kernel code running on a CPU device (MAC)?
I can use printfs but I would like to step into kernel code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe not. The ability is not mentioned in the "Debugging" section of the OpenCL for OSX [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/) (and [PDF](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/OpenCL_MacProgGuide.pdf)).

Comment: With Intel SDK it is possible but not with OSXs. so I could only use prints. I was wondering if I could get mangled names of the kernel function name probably I have a break point but not sure how I could do that.